# Pass empty string (double quote) argument to dockerfile

Tags: docker, build, pecl

My project wrapped by Docker and run in 2 environments: **behind proxy** or **no proxy**.

In this case, I use *php:apache* image and install ext via pecl, so I must set proxy manually

```
FROM php:apache

RUN pear config-set http_proxy $http_proxy
# RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

The `$http_proxy` arg will passed from docker-compose in 2 values: `http://server:port` or `“”` (double quote)

But when build the custom image in case `“”`, the `$http_proxy` arg was null, and show error in the config command

> Step 4/4 : RUN pear config-set http_proxy $http_proxy
>
> —> Running in 19b69d089ff2
>
> config-set expects 2 or 3 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a `RUN` command, you can add a test:

```
docker build -t my_apache .  --build-arg http_proxy=....
```

With a Dockerfile:

```
ARG http_proxy
RUN if [ "x$http_proxy" != "x" ] ; then  pear config-set http_proxy $http_proxy; fi
```

You actually don't need the `ARG http_proxy` as it is [one of the predefined ones](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#predefined-args).